# RVM upgrade 2.5.0 issues

Tags: ruby, rvm

Hello I am currently using RVM version 1.29.3 and Ruby 2.4.2 and I am unable to upgrade to 2.4.3 or 2.5.0. When I run `rvm upgrade 2.5.0`, output is `Are you sure you wish to upgrade from ruby-2.4.2 to ruby-2.4.1? (Y/n):` which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: If you issue the command `rvm list known` and it doesn't have the latest, you probably need to update rvm first via `rvm get stable`. Did you try that?

Comment: Hmm, the latest is is not listed when I run `rvm list known` but I have already tried updating using `rvm get stable` multiple times so that should be the most current!

Comment: What happens when you run `rvm install 2.5.0`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Often, new releases of Ruby are not available on *stable* versions of rvm, and if you want them you need to install the *head*. As previously stated, you can do `rvm get head`. New windows will use the new version of `rvm` but if you use a terminal window that was loaded before installing the new version of rvm, you'll need to do a `rvm reload`.

Then you should be able to `rvm install 2.5`.

(Do not then do `rvm get stable` because it will overwrite the `head` version.)

Comment: Thanks, Keith! I am still running into a configure error when installing 2.5, but this was the key to getting rvm updated correctly to list the correct versions of Ruby.

Comment: @BlueFox22 If your error had anything to do with SSL, then it may be solved by doing a `brew install openssl` and then when you install the Ruby interpreter, tell rvm to use Brew's copy of OpenSSL: `rvm install 2.5 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`